# Property 'exhibitPhotos' does not exist on type 'unknown' in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise

From an Object, I want loop through its `exhibitPhotos` array and push the data into another array, but I keep gettting the error `Property 'exhibitPhotos' does not exist on type 'unknown'`.

```js
  exhibitImages: any[] = [];
  @Input() exhibitImagesId: string;

  constructor(
    private contentfulService: ContentfulService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contentfulService.getExhibitImages(this.exhibitImagesId)
      .then((images) => {
        images.fields.exhibitPhotos.forEach(image => {
          this.exhibitImages.push(image);
        });
      });
  }
```

I am confused because looking at the console.log (screenshot below), there is the Property `exhibitPhotos`:

[image]

What am I missing?

(Further)

So I did some more trying outs and it gets wieder.

Anying I log from `sys` works fine. For example: `console.log(images.sys.id)` correctly `returns` the `id`.

But, anything from `fields`, will simply give me the same error. Apart from the array I wish to access described above, simply `images.fields.title` `returns` the error.

Comment: Two things, First please check whether images has a property fields and it has property exhibitPhotos and Second as you are pushing data to this.exhibitImages, initialize the array exhibitImages to empty array `exhibitImages: any[] = [];

Comment: You don't have to loop the array to assign to another variable. First assign an empty array during declaration `exhibitImages = [];`. And try to assign it using `this.exhibitImages = images['fields']['exhibitPhotos'];`.

Comment: @Ravi `images.fields` definitely has the property `exhibitPhotos` as can be seen from the logged object (scrrenshot). The second, point, I have done it now.

Comment: @MichaelD Well it is a step closer. I am returned the array `exhibitPhotos`from the the Object using your syntax. And so I have also taken your advice and done this `.then(images => this.exhibitImages = images['fields']['exhibitPhotos']);`  but now get the error `TypeError: images is undefined`

Comment: @kontenurban: Please show the `getExhibitImages()` function from the service.

Comment: Try `.then((images: any) => {images.fields.exhibitPhotos...`